# Is there any way to know a component is on screen in ReactNative? like viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear

Tags: react-native

If you're writing Swift you can use ViewController's life cycle hook, viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear to know whether specific View is on screen. 
Is there any way to do the similar thing in ReactNative? looks like no close one in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think react native provides any functions which are called when you pop to previous view(unlike methods like componentWillMount() which is called when component mounts).

But I think you can pass a callback function when you navigate to new scene, and just before popping it call this function.

When you push a new component `'B'` from `'A'`

In `Component A`

```
callBackPop() {

 // manipulate state
}

pushNewScene() {
  this.props.navigator.push({name: 'B', callBack: this.callBackPop});
}
```

In `Navigator`

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {

  <B navigator={navigator} callback={route.callBack} />

}
```

In `Component B`

```
function popToPrevious() {
     this.props.callBack();

     this.props.navigator.pop();

}
```

Comment: events for app state is not what this is about. this is about views becoming visible when navigating. On iOS views have events for didAppear, willAppear etc.

Answer (score -2):

What you're looking for is for React component lifecycle methods, specifically **componentDidMount**. Check it out in the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Comment: Thanks. But it is only the case when the component is **newly** appeared. When you use Navigator or NavigationExperimental, you use pop to previous page to get back it again. but the component is already mounted so the componentDidMount method is not gonna be called. What I am looking for is a way to know the component appeared on screen even if it is already mounted component.

Comment: Mmm... I see, so you want to check if the component is still there when you go back to the screen? Maybe trying a **forceUpdate** on the component you are watching? [forceUpdate docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)